# aggregation in mongodb with push

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a JOIN between two collections and I'm new to MongoDB. I am trying to do it by means of aggregations.

I have two collections that relate the sensors and measurements, and in the collection of measures introduce two fields that are in the collection of sensors.

For example this is my sensor collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId ("5b4de5121852a4b3ae632db5"),
    "name": "var_ContadorRiego",
    "type": "resources",
    "place": "interior",
    "img": "img / imgriego",
    "user": ObjectId ("5b10176084195a07f63c942a"),
    "greenhouse": ObjectId ("5b1027896933440c030f8a6b"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

Where I need to recover the place and img field in the response of the measurement collection.

My collection of measurements:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId ("5ab5a77898492a1703b7d398"),
    "recvTime": ISODate ("2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z"),
    "attrName": "var_ContadorRiego",
    "attrType": "float",
    "attrValue": "0"
}
```

I need the answer to be this:

an aggregation by date and with those two fields.

```
{
    "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
        {
            "_id": "2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z",
            "measurements": [
                {
                    "attrName": "var_TempHumosCaldera",
                    "count": 1,
                    "attrValue": "17.081713",
                    "place": "interior",
                    "img": "img / imgtemphum",
                },
                {
                    "attrName": "var_TempExt",
                    "count": 1,
                    "attrValue": "12.511116",
                    "place": "outside",
                    "img": "img / imgtemp",
                },
                {
                    "attrName": "var_ContadorRiego",
                    "count": 1,
                    "attrValue": "0",
                    "place": "outside",
                    "img": "img / imgContRi",
                }
            ],
            "count": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

for now I have only managed to work without these two fields with this code:

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate ([

    {"$ match": {
    "attrName": {$ in: arr}}},
    / * {
      "$ lookup": {
          "from": "sensors",
          "localField": "sensor",
          "foreignField": "attrName",
          "as": "sensor"
      }
    }, * /
    // {"$ unwind": "$ sensor"},
    {"$ group": {
        "_id": {
            "recvTime": "$ recvTime",
            "attrName": "$ attrName",
            "attrValue": "$ attrValue",
            // "sensor_type": "$ sensor.type",
            //"place":"$sensor.place "

        },
        // "sensor": {"$ first": "$ sensor"},
        //"place":{"$first":"$sensor.place "},
        "Count": {"$ sum": 1}
    }},

    // {$ unwind: '$ type'},
    {"$ group": {
        "_id": "$ _id.recvTime",
        "measurements": {
            "$ push": {
                "attrName": "$ _id.attrName",
                "count": "$ Count",
                "attrValue": "$ _id.attrValue",
                // "sensor_type": "$ _id.sensor_type",
                // "sensor": "$ sensor"
                // "sensor_type": "$ _id.sensor_type",
                // "place": "$ place"
                // "sensor_type": "$ _id.sensor_type",
                //"place":"$_id.place "
            },
        },
        "count": {"$ sum": "$ Count"}
    }},
    {"$ sort": {"_id": -1}},
    {"$ limit": 1}
    ]
```

As you can see I have used the lookup and the unwind, but I can not get it to work as I want, besides what I have shown it does not correspond, for example, if I have shown the image and the place but of other sensors not of the one with that name.

How can I solve this problem, I'm stuck and I do not get out.

Greetings and thank you.

EDIT01

This is my final code

Datagreenhouse.aggregate([

```
  {"$match":{"attrName":{"$in":arr}}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"sensors",
    "localField":"attrName", // local field in measurements collection
    "foreignField":"name", //foreign field from sensors collection
    "as":"sensor"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$sensor"},
  {"$addFields":{
    "place":"$sensor.place",// Add place to the measurements
    "img":"$sensor.img"// Add img to the measurements

  }},



  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$recvTime",
      "medidas": {
          "$push": {
              "attrName": "$attrName",
              "attrValue": "$attrValue",
              "sensor": "$sensor"

          },
      },
      "count": { "$sum": "$Count" }
  }},
  {"$sort":{"_id":-1}},
  {"$limit":1}
    ]
```

How could I add the sensor object my two fields of measurements:

Now I have this answer:

```
{
    "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
        {
            "_id": "2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z",
            "measurements": [
                {
                    "attrName": "var_ContadorRiego",
                    "attrValue": "0",
                    "sensor": {
                        "_id": "5b4de5121852a4b3ae632db5",
                        "name": "var_ContadorRiego",
                        "type": "resources",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets / img / temp.png",
                        "user": "5b10176084195a07f63c942a",
                        "greenhouse": "5b1027896933440c030f8a6b",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attrName": "var_PotActBio",
                    "attrValue": "8.384025",
                    "sensor": {
                        "_id": "5b4de5121852a4b3ae632db3",
                        "name": "var_PotActBio",
                        "type": "resources",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets / img / temp.png",
                        "user": "5b10176084195a07f63c942a",
                        "greenhouse": "5b1027896933440c030f8a6b",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attrName": "var_PotActInv",
                    "attrValue": "0.130222",
                    "sensor": {
                        "_id": "5b4de5121852a4b3ae632db1",
                        "name": "var_PotActInv",
                        "type": "resources",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets / img / temp.png",
                        "user": "5b10176084195a07f63c942a",
                        "greenhouse": "5b1027896933440c030f8a6b",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attrName": "var_TempExt",
                    "attrValue": "12.511116",
                    "sensor": {
                        "_id": "5ab5a77898492a1703b7d3d9",
                        "name": "var_TempExt",
                        "type": "climate",
                        "place": "outside",
                        "img": "assets / img / temp.png",
                        "user": "5b10176084195a07f63c942a",
                        "greenhouse": "5b1027896933440c030f8a6b",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "count": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Would it be possible to have something like that?

```
{
    "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
        {
            "_id": "2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z",
            "measurements": [
                {
                    
                    "sensor": {
                        "_id": "5b4de5121852a4b3ae632db5",
                        "name": "var_ContadorRiego",
                        "type": "resources",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets / img / temp.png",
                        "user": "5b10176084195a07f63c942a",
                        "greenhouse": "5b1027896933440c030f8a6b",
"attrName": "var_ContadorRiego",
                    "attrValue": "0",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attrName": "var_PotActBio",
                    "attrValue": "8.384025",
                    "sensor": {
                        "_id": "5b4de5121852a4b3ae632db3",
                        "name": "var_PotActBio",
                        "type": "resources",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets / img / temp.png",
                        "user": "5b10176084195a07f63c942a",
                        "greenhouse": "5b1027896933440c030f8a6b",
"attrName": "var_ContadorRiego",
                    "attrValue": "0",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attrName": "var_PotActInv",
                    "attrValue": "0.130222",
                    "sensor": {
                        "_id": "5b4de5121852a4b3ae632db1",
                        "name": "var_PotActInv",
                        "type": "resources",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets / img / temp.png",
                        "user": "5b10176084195a07f63c942a",
                        "greenhouse": "5b1027896933440c030f8a6b",
"attrName": "var_ContadorRiego",
                    "attrValue": "0",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What does the count represent here ? Is it same as length of measurement array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your aggregation pipeline to below.

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"attrName":{"$in":arr}}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"sensors",
    "localField":"attrName", // local field in measurements collection
    "foreignField":"name", //foreign field from sensors collection
    "as":"sensor"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$sensor"},
  {"$addFields":{
    "sensor.attrName":"$attrName",// Add attrName to the sensors
    "sensor.attrValue":"$attrValue",// Add attrValue to the sensors
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$recvTime", // Group by time
    "measurements":{"$push":"$sensor"}, // Collect measurements
    "count":{"$sum":1} // Count measurements
  }},
  {"$sort":{"_id":-1}},
  {"$limit":1}
])
```

Comment: That does not work for me, it gives me this answer:

{
    "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
        {
            "_id": "2018-03-24T01:18:18.619Z",
            "measurements": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "count": 4
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Can you show me your query pls ? Where are those zeros coming from ? Run your query with only  match and lookup and let me know what about you see.

Comment: I have removed "sensor": 0 and now it only shows me the information of the sensor collection, but nothing of the measurements collection. I'm trying to pass the attrValue to the collection of measurements.

Comment: Can you make sure your  foreign collection name along with local and foreign field matches to what you have in collection ?

Comment: if the fields are correct, but at no time I see that you are calling the field attrValue in what you have added.

Comment: Fixed. I should be using $$ROOT instead of sensor in push.

Comment: Ok it seems that we are improving I have managed to show the information of the two collections, a question is possible to show everything in the same object sensors, I add the post

Comment: I didn't get your question. Can you rephrase the question pls ?

Comment: Please add the addFields stage with sensor:0 back. This will remove the sensor data from response. We have already added the field that we need form sensor collection into main document.

Comment: if I add that, it returns the 0 that I mentioned earlier